# can the derivative of a closed complex contour at any point be zero?

Tags: complex-analysis, derivatives, complex-numbers, parametric

If C is a **closed** contour in the complex plane parametrized by z(t)=u(t)+i*v(t), can there be any point where z'(t)=0?

Comment: $$z(t) = e^{it^3}; \quad t\in [-\sqrt[3]{\pi},\sqrt[3]{\pi}]$$

Comment: Thanks! I feel like an idiot (I was trying various Lissajous curves, but like most of mathematics, the answer was far simpler than I thought)

Comment: @nicbit perhaps more interestingly, a closed smooth contour can admit a paramtrization with a non-vanishing derivative (so, we may assume w.l.o.g that no such point exists).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, as was shown by Daniel Fischer: 
$$z(t) = e^{it^3}; \quad t\in [-\sqrt[3]{\pi},\sqrt[3]{\pi}]$$

(Or take any closed contour and compose its parametrization with $(t-a)^3$.)